# Values in XML Attributes no longer accepted as valid after upgrading to Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

After upgrading to Android Studio my styles.xml suddenly has lots of errors.

[image: Theme... is no longer recognized]

When trying to change the parent property Android Studio suggests 'TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar' as a valid value when typing...

Also I had to prefix ?attr/... attributes with ?android:attr like below...

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Note that my app will compile and run...

Are these bugs? (probably...)

If not; What is the reason for the change?

If so; What prefix is missing for my themes?

Thanks, Ove

Comment: I have the same issue...I think that is a bug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved after Sync project with Gradle, Clean , Rebuild the Project. I think it is a bug of android studio 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I get that from time to time as well, I usually try the following:

- Clean & Rebuild Project
- Sync project with Gradle files
- File -> Invalidate caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

A combination of these in a random order usually solves it (I know, I know, really scientific method... but hey as long as it works :))